# Bottom Navigation Bar being pushed out of view by a Scrollview Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

cutting straight to the chase. I want to have a bottom navigation bar for my application, and then at the top there is a toolbar, in the middle will be a scrollview where the contents will be placed.

The problem now here is that the ScrollView layout pushes the navigation bar out of view, and now the navigation bar won't show.

[As you can see, the navigation bar isn't showing because the ScrollView takes up the bottom of the screen too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z18xh.png)

Another solution I've tried but it turned out the navigation bar pops up on top of the ScrollView

[That blue bar below the Home toolbar is the navigation bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isKJP.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="polytechnic.temasek.bluebeatsmusicapplication.HomePageActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluebeatsbackground2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="539dp"
    >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

            [Content inside] 
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/the_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

So far, I've only been able to bruteforce the Scrollview's height to a certain dp to make room for the navigation bar, but there must be another way which I'm supposedly missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could better use **Relative Layout** or **Constraint Layout** (*I recommend to use **Constraint Layout***) to handle such situations.

I have modified your layout to Constraint Layout.
I've tricked the scrollbar's marginBottom value to height of the bottomNavigationBar [Else, some of the contents of scrollView remain behind the bottomNavBar].

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/long_text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/the_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, this solution worked fine but I'm interested to know why you changed from using linearlayout to constraint or relative?

Comment: [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) has many advantages over the other layouts: * More control among your views. * Less nested layouts. * Write less code. (Most of the work can be done in Layout editor.) and much more... Just go through some tutorials & you will definitely find it easier(Looks complex ;)). Accept the answer if it worked ;P